# Count number of lines with a certain value in a column for all files in directory recursively

Tags: bash, find, awk, search, recursive

I have 40 files in a directory and I want to count the number of times there is a line with a "2" in the first column in each file individually.

I am trying something like this, but it prints out the total sum from each file and I want the individual sums:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 awk '($1=="2"){++count} END {print count}'
```

Just to make it clear this is an example:

FILE_1

```
2   345     123     4
2   4567    2344    6
3   2345    657     87
6   234     345     6
```

FILE_2

```
1   12  436 7
2   54  86  8
2   23  48  0
2   098 0   8
8   98  9   0
```

PRINT:

```
FILE_1 2
FILE_2 3
```

What I'm actually getting:

PRINT:

```
5
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `grep` count them for you.
Assuming the lines you need start with `2`, you can use the following:

```
grep -c '^[[:space:]]*2\>' $(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo)
```

The `\>` at the end of the regex ensures matching will stop at a "word boundary" to avoid false alarms such as lines starting with 20 instead of 2.

**Note:**

If the "40 files" you're looking for are all in the same directory (not in sub-directories), you can make `find` search the current directory only without recursing (so that you get less latency) like so:

```
find -maxdepth 1 . -type f -print0
```

**Update:**

To match files where the 2 occurs in a different column to the first, you can do this:

```
COLNUM=3
TOMATCH=$(($COLNUM-1))
grep -cE "^[[:space:]]*([0-9]+[[:space:]]+){$TOMATCH}2\>" \
$(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo)
```

You can change `COLNUM` as needed. Basically, what this does is, it attempts to match `COLNUM-1` columns followed by a 2 at a word boundary. The `-E` switch is needed to enable extended regular expressions which allows you to use the `{}` notation to specify a numerical quantifier (i.e. 'match the previous pattern this many times').

Note however,that if you enter a column number that doesn't exist in the file the regex will fail silently.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting more because it was also counting lines that had other values (20 for example) that started with a 2 but I fixed it with grep -wc

Comment: @Rebe Edited answer to make a provision for that in the regex.

Comment: @Rebe You should note that this solution doesn't scale well as the `find` command needs to have listed all the files before the `grep` begins. If you're looking at a large number of files, the pipe-lined solutions in the other answers are probably more well-suited for you.

Comment: Can you use grep to find a value in a different column and not just at the start of the line?

Comment: @Rebe Give me more info: are "columns" made up of digits only? Are we sure that columns are delimited by whitespace only?

Comment: @Rebe Also, is a Perl solution acceptable to you?

Comment: Sure, columns are digits only, delimited by tabs. The awk answer posted below can do that, but I was wondering if it can be done with grep as well. Perl is acceptable too.

Comment: @Rebe Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of solutions:

1. execute `awk` on each file using `find` `-exec` option:

   ```
   find . -type f \
   -exec awk '($1=="2"){++count}END{print FILENAME ": " count}' {} \;
   ```
2. use awk `FNR` variable to detect file change in awk script:

   ```
   find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 \
   awk 'FNR==1{if (NR!=1){print count} printf("%s: ", FILENAME);}($1=="2"){++count}END{print count}'
   ```

Comment: The first one works great. The second one isn't what I'm really looking for but it's good to know ho to do that. Thanks!

Comment: And I like that it uses awk so I can use it for other columns!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the output you can do the following:

```
$ grep "^2" *|awk '{print $1}'|uniq -c
      2 FILE_1:2
      3 FILE_2:2
```

If you want your PRINT output:

```
$ grep "^2" *|awk '{print $1}'|uniq -c|sed 's/:2//'|awk '{print $2, $1}'
FILE_1 2
FILE_2 3
```

Comment: @Rebe - yeah it's less efficient but easier to follow.